# jqgrid - double clicking a row selects the row in IE8

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

When I double click a row it is selecting the row in IE8 but not in FF and Chrome. Is it an issue in IE8 or is there any bug for this? Thanks...

Comment: Which behavior you would like? Try the same in [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithColumnChooser5.htm) for example. Can you reproduce the "double click" in the demo?

Comment: Hi Oleg, I have the multiselect: true option, the demo has no check boxes. When I have that option, double clicking a row, selects(highlights) the row. As I mentioned, it is not the same in FF and chrome...

Comment: I have added multiselect: true in your demo code and tested it locally, it has the same issue that I reported. Thanks...

Comment: Regarding behavior, I do not want the row to be selected automatically when I double click on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior is well-know. For example you can read the following in the documentation of the [jQuery.dblclick](http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/):

> The sequence of events triggered varies from browser to browser, with
>   some receiving two click events before the dblclick and others only
>   one. Double-click sensitivity (maximum time between clicks that is
>   detected as a double click) can vary by operating system and browser,
>   and is often user-configurable.

If you want common behavior in all browsers you code do the following:

```
ondblClickRow: function (rowid) {
    if ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) < 9) {
        $(this).jqGrid('setSelection', rowid, false);
    }
}
```

see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SelectionOnDoubleClick.htm) or the opposite behavior with the code

```
ondblClickRow: function (rowid) {
    if (!$.browser.msie || parseInt($.browser.version, 10) > 8) {
        $(this).jqGrid('setSelection', rowid, false);
    }
}
```

see [another demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SelectionOnDoubleClick_.htm).

Comment: Oleg: Thanks a lot for the solution with detailed explanation. You are so helpful!